# HebMorph with solr: how to use stopwords

Tags: solr, information-retrieval, hebrew, synonym, stop-words

I am developing an application that supports indexing & searching of multi-language texts, including hebrew, using the "solr" engine.

After lots of searches, I found that HebMorph is the best plugin to use for hebrew language

My problem is that the behavior of HebMorph with hebrew stopwords seems to be different than solr:

- Whith solr (any language): when I search for a stopword, the results returned doesn't include any of the stopwords exxisting in query.
- Whereas when I search for hebrew terms (after pluging HebMorh in solr following [this link](https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph/blob/master/SOLR-README.md), the returned results include all existing stopwords in the query.

**1)** Is this the normal behavior for HebMorph? If yes, how can I alter it? If no, what should I change?

**2)** Since HebMorph doesn't support synonyms, (as I read in their documentation that it is a future work). Is there a way to use synonyms for hebrew as other languages the way solr supports it? (i.e. by adding the proper filter in solrconfig and pointing out to the synonyms file)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just as a heads up, the link in your question is broken (link [1])

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - stopwords are not removed from the content returned by Solr - the stored content is the same as what was submitted. Stopwords are removed after tokenization, and only affects what would generate a hit. Since there isn't a specific stopwordfilter in HebMorph as far as I can see, do you have any examples from the analysis page under Solr's Admin that shows your issue?

Comment: @Jayce444: I tried it, it's working fine. Any way, this is the url: https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph/blob/master/SOLR-README.md

Comment: @MatsLindh, thank's for your reply. The content should stay as is, I meant that if the query you send to solr contains a stopword (in hebrew), it will be treated as a term that should be searched for, whereas, in Solr, when you add stopwords filter, theses words won't be searched for in docs. Any way I will try to give a snapshot about the analysis.

Comment: @MatsLindh, when analyzing any phrase or term in the analysis page under Solr's Admin, the only filter that is applied id **[addSuffixTokenFilters]** that is used by the HebrewAnalyzer of HebMorph.

Comment: I think the author's answer is the way forward - it seems the HebMorph plugin doesn't fit into the regular analysis chains.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh for your reply. I understood that HebMorph doesn't fit into the regular analysis chains, but my question is: "Is there a way that I can add StopWordsFilter or something that I can do to make HebMorph drop stopwords on query (i.e.: doesn't search for stop words in solr doc and by result don't return results for them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of HebMorph.

StopWords are indeed supported, but you need to filter them out before the lemmatizer kicks in. Assuming a recent version of HebMorph - your stopwords filter needs to come in right after the tokenizer, which means it needs to take care also of בחל"מ letters attached to the stop-words.

The general advice nowadays, for all languages, is NOT to drop stopwords - at least not in indexing, so I'd recommend not applying a stop-words filter here either.

With regards to synonyms - the root issue is with the HebMorph lemmatizer expanding a word to multiple lemmas at times, which makes the work of applying synonyms a bit more challenging. With the (relatively) new graph based analyzers this is now possible to do so we will likely implement that too and Lucene's Synonym filters will be supported OOTB.

In the commercial version there is already a way to customize word lists and override dictionary definitions, which is useful in an ambiguous language like Hebrew. Many use this as their way of creating synonyms.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried to use stopFilterFactory after defining the analyzer, but Solr failed to init core, giving me this exception: Analyzer class='org.apache.lucene.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer' can noot be combied with nested analysis factories. Note that I am using HebMmorph 6.6.1..

Comment: How can I "filter them out before the lemmatizer kicks in"? is there a way to do it by configuration in managed schema?

Comment: So I understand that there is no way to perform what I'mlooking to achieve with HebMorph @synhershko ?